# faithfully flat ring extensions where primes extend to primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I am interested in unital ring homomorphisms (and classes thereof) $R \rightarrow S$ of commutative rings that have the following pair of properties:

- $S$ is faithfully flat as an $R$-module, and
- For any prime ideal $P$ of $R$, $PS$ is a prime ideal of $S$.

I know of the following examples:

- $R \rightarrow R[X]$, where $X$ is an indeterminate over $R$ (or any set of algebraically independent indeterminates over $R$)
- $R \rightarrow R[[X]]$, where $X$ is an analytic indeterminate over $R$ (or any finite set of such)
- If $R$ is a field, take any (unital) ring map $R \rightarrow S$ such that $S$ is an integral domain.
- If $R$ is a Noetherian valuation domain, the map $R \rightarrow \hat{R}$ will work.
- Whenever $g: R \rightarrow S$ is an example of this and $W$ is a multiplicatively closed subset of $S$ such that $m S_W \neq S_W$ for any maximal ideal $m$ of $R$, then the induced map $R \rightarrow S_W$ works as well.  (Some other localizations will be fine too.)

Then there are cases that *sometimes* work.  For instance, one might expect $R \rightarrow \hat{R}$ to work, where $(R,m)$ is an arbitrary Noetherian local ring and $\hat{R}$ is its $m$-adic completion.  (As noted above, this works for valuation rings.)  However, it only works when $R/p$ is analytically irreducible for every prime ideal $p$ of $R$.  It fails, for instance, when $R$ is the localization of $k[x,y]$ at $(x,y)$ when $k$ is a field of characteristic other than $2$.  (This is because the element $x^2-y^2-y^3$ is prime in $R$ but not in $\hat{R}$.)

Do people know of any other important examples?

Answer (score 4):

This question might be easier to consider geometrically.

You want the morphism $\operatorname{Spec}S \to \operatorname{Spec}R$ to be faithfully flat, and the fibre over each point $\mathfrak p \in \operatorname{Spec}R$ (which equals $\operatorname{Spec}S\otimes_R \kappa(\mathfrak p)$, where $\kappa(\mathfrak p)$ 
is the residue field of $R/\mathfrak p$) should be integral.
(Actually, the question asks that $S/\mathfrak p S$ be integral,
but since $S$ is flat over $R$ by assumption, the embedding $R/\mathfrak p \hookrightarrow \kappa(\mathfrak p)$
induces an embedding $S/\mathfrak p S \hookrightarrow S\otimes_R \kappa(\mathfrak p).$ Thus if the target is a domain, so is the source,
and conversely, since the target is a localization of the source.)

So for example, any smooth morphism of affine varieties all of whose fibres are connected will give an example. (Since a smooth connected variety is irreducible.)

This will give an enormous class of examples.

E.g.
as a slight variation on the preceding remark, let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, and let $A \subset B$ an inclusion of f.g. $k$-algebras that are domains, such that, if $K$ denotes
the algebraic closure of $\operatorname{Frac}(A)$, then $K\otimes_A B$ is a domain.
(In other words, the generic fibre of the map $\operatorname{Spec}B \to \operatorname{Spec}A$ is geometrically irreducible.)  Then over some non-empty open subset of $\operatorname{Spec}A$ the restriction of $\operatorname{Spec}A \to\operatorname{Spec}B$ will be faithfully flat
and will have geometrically irreducible fibres, and hence
we can find $a \neq 0$ such that $A[1/a] \to B[1/a]$ will have the desired property.

A concrete example is given by the inclusion
$\mathbb C[t] \subset \mathbb C[x,y,t]/(y^2 - x(x-1)(x-t)),$
but there is nothing particularly special about this example;
it is just my favorite example of a flat family of irreducible
curves.

Added: This is an example taken from the discussion in comments below.  It
is intended to illustrate why the above example is not particularly special or limited in scope.

Let $A$ be any f.g. $k$-algebra, and let $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ be a polynomial
whose coefficients are elements of $A$, i.e. $f \in A[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.
Now consider the ring $B = A[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/(f)$.

Geometrically, $f$ is the equation for a family of hypersurfaces, parameterized by $\operatorname{Spec}A$.

Again, suppose that $A$ is a domain (so $\operatorname{Spec}A$ is a variety), and let $a \in A$ be the discriminant of $f$.  Unless you are very unlucky
in your choice, $a$ will be non-zero. (Geometrically, this is saying that
the family of hypersurfaces $f=0$ doesn't have *every* member being singular.  Of course it could, if you chose it that way, but if you choose it generically, then it won't.)  So if we pass to $A[1/a]$ and $B[1/a]$, we have a family of smooth hypersurfaces. Provided that $n \geq 2$, a smooth hypersurface is irreducible, so $A[1/a] \subset B[1/a]$ will satisfy the conditions of the problem.

[In the  example with cubic curves, I didn't invert the discriminant, because I happened to choose a flat family of curves which remain irreducible even when they become singular.]

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you saying that if Spec $S/pS$ is connected, then $S/pS$ is an integral domain?  I thought connectedness just meant that the ring isn't a product of nontrivial subrings.

Comment: Also, isn't the usual definition of "fiber over a point $p$" then "Spec $S_p / p S_p$"?  If so, that would explain your linking of connectedness with integrality.

Comment: @neilme: Dear neilme, I wrote the first version of the answer in some haste, but have corrected/amplified it.  If you still have questions, let me know.  Regards,

Comment: Dear Matt: That is a very nice restatement of the problem in geometric language.  Thank you for that!  However, I still don't quite see how to use it to get many examples (though I do like your flat family).  The geometric properties you list seem just as tricky, if not more so, to check than the original conditions.  Can you say more about this?

Comment: ...for instance, how would one know whether the generic fiber were geometrically irreducible?  The ring $K \otimes_A B$ looks pretty intractable to me.

Comment: @neilme: Dear neilme, By assumption $B$ is f.g. over $k$, hence f.g. over $A$.  Write $B = A[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/(f_1,\ldots,f_r)$.  Then $K \otimes_A B = K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/(f_1,\ldots,f_r)$, and we are asking if $f_1,\ldots,f_r$ cut out an irreducible variety over $K$.  This can be a complicated question if the $f_i$ are complicated equations, but it needn't be.  E.g. suppose that $r = 1$, so that we are just looking at a single hypersurface $f = 0$ in $\mathbb A^n$.  Then you are asking if this hypersurface is irreducible, which is pretty easy: it is just a question as to whether or not $f$ ...

Comment: ... is irreducible.  In the example I gave, $f$ is the equation $y^2 = x(x-1)(x-t)$, which is known to be irreducible over (the alg. closure of) $\mathbb C(t)$, since it is a smooth cubic.  In general, if $f$ cuts out a smooth hypersurface (which you can test just by the non-vanishing of some partial derivative, so not difficult at all) then it will also cut out an irreducible hypersurface (smooth implies irreducible for hypersurfaces, as long as $n \geq 2$).  So this gives *lots* of examples.  E.g. take any family of hypersurfaces depending on parameters (so $A$ is the ring of parameters, ...

Comment: ... and $B$ is the ring $A[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/(f)$ where $f$ is the hypersurface equation depending on the parameters in $A$).  Then the discriminant of $f$ will be an element $a \in A$, and as long as it is not identically zero (i.e. as long as not *all* the hypersurfaces in the family are singular) then we can pass to $B[1/a]$ over $A[1/a]$ and get a family with smooth, hence irreducible, fibres.   Do you see now why I say there are lots of examples?  It's because there are all these families of irreducible hypersurfaces out there (and lots of other families of varieties that don't happen ...

Comment: ... to be hypersurfaces; but the hypersurface examples are the easiest to write down and check).  Regards,

Comment: What is the discriminant of a multivariable polynomial?

Comment: @neilme: Dear neilme, It will be the resultant of $f$ and all its partial derivatives, and will vanish exactly at the singular points of the variety $f= 0$.  Regards,

Comment: Wonderful!  Where can I find references on these topics? (e.g. is it all in Hartshorne? stacks project?)

Comment: @neilme: Dear neilme, I'm not sure, unfortunately.  I would try one of Joe Harris's more expository alg. geom. books rather than Hartshorne or Stacks.  If you can find a discussion by him (or anyone) of the space of hypersurfaces, you'll see that they talk about the *disciminant locus* as a synonym for the closed sublocus of singular hypersurfaces, and you hopefully can find a more careful discussion of what the discriminant is, etc.  Also, I am probably being too blase in my discussion of discriminans overall, ...

Comment: ... as [this MO question and its answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52391/testing-whether-a-hypersurface-is-singular) suggest.  On the other hand, [this write-up](http://math.arizona.edu/~eacosta/pdfs/docs/Spaces.pdf) (which I found just by googling) seems like a pretty good guide, with both useful information and useful literature references.  Regards,